# NuGet.exe : Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to push my nuget package to a private Nuget Server and I keep getting the error that I didn't specify a username when pushing my nuget package to the server.

How do I specify the username in the package manager prompt?

Here is the error: NuGet.exe : Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.

I can't find my nuget.config file also, otherwise I could modify that.   I have a packages.config file.

Answer (score 0):

For NuGet.exe behavior (such as restore/push url of packageSource and authentication) use the NuGet.Config (not packges.config) It is located in your userprofile or as a machine-wide config. 
read all about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file

a configuration could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="PackagesAll" value="https://mystore.myCompany.net/api/nuget/" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <PackagesAll>
      <add key="Username" value="gitUser" />
      <add key="Password" value="FSW4SNXXX" />
    </PackagesAll>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```